# Reading dxf file special characters

Tags: c#, file, dxf

When I'm reading a `TXT` file with "special" characters it works perfectly fine. But when I read a `DXF` file, it translates it to the wrong characters (see image below).

is the `iso-8859-1` not the correct encoding for DXF files?
[image: R]

Comment: I strongly suspect it's UTF-8. Have you tried that? See also: https://ezdxf.readthedocs.io/en/master/dxfinternals/fileencoding.html

Comment: Also note "When I'm reading a TXT file with "special" characters it works perfectly fine" - well that depends on which encoding was used to write the text file.

Comment: @jonSkeet I created the file myself for testing with notepad

Comment: Right. But Notepad has multiple options for which encoding to use. Presumably you happened to use one that's compatible with ISO-8859-1. But plain text files can use *any* encoding - you shouldn't assume that every file with a `.txt` extension uses ISO-8859-1.

Comment: Yea it's UTF-8. If you give an answer I can set it as answered. How can Is there a way to check a files encoding?

Comment: You can't, in general. It's entirely possible for a file to be equally valid, but have a different meaning, in multiple encodings. UTF-8 is the most common default these days though, in my experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this documentation](https://ezdxf.readthedocs.io/en/master/dxfinternals/fileencoding.html), DXF files have been written using UTF-8 since DXF R2007. This makes them much more portable than depending on a specific code page.

That's also the default for `File.ReadAllLines`, so you can just use `File.ReadAllLines(FileName)`.

Comment: Yea that's it! Thanks for your help!